# Mongo chart behind nginx

Tags: mongodb, nginx, charts, docker-compose, mongodb-stitch

I have docker container created from "quay.io/mongodb/charts:19.12.1" for mongodb chart.

- Here my container url is  http://intenal.nosql.chart//, This url is accessible inside my docker network and it is working  perfectly.
- Now I want to expose this url to public domain via nginx  at  http://mypublicdomain.com/mongo/chart.

I have below configuration in nginx

```
location /mongo/chart/ {
    proxy_pass "http://intenal.nosql.chart/";
}
```

Now if i access my chart from http://mypublicdomain.com/mongo/chart, it is not working. it seems there is error related to baseurl.

So what should i do in mongodb chart to take difference base url

Answer (score 1):

I have to add following header in ngnix

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://intenal.nosql.chart/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port; 
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```